# Write a sybase PROC to interate through each table and truncate?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sap-ase

I am running Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.7, please could anyone tell me how to write a procedure that iterates through each table within the database and truncates the data in each table.

Thanks
:-)

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways:

(i) write it yourself by cycling over sysobjects and constructing a truncate table command for every table found, and then executing it with exec(@cmd).

(ii) download my stored procs from http://www.sypron.nl/new_ssp_dwn.html, install them and then run:

sp_rv_findobject 'db=your_db_name', type=U', 'exec=immediate', 'execarg=truncate table OW.NM'

Comment: Hmm cant download yours as its not convenient. Please write one. Thank you please.

Comment: What's wrong with the download link? It works for me.

Comment: Sorry cannot download, could you paste some code please :-)